# Is there any good material about the working mechanism of IIS hosting WCF web service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, iis-7

It is just magic that I put some file in my site's Bin folder and place a svc file to point to some assembly pointing to my service type. And then, I could magically Add Service Reference to the url like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com//xxx.svc
```

I really want to know how what happens from my click "Add Service Reference" to the proxy is generated properly. What does the IIS do during this period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really magic - it's metadata exchange ! :-)

When you do a `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio, behind the scenes, that service endpoint specified by the svc file is interrogated for its metadata. This is basically similar to a WSDL (Web Service Description Language) file - a machine-readable description of your service, its methods, what parameters they expect etc. - and a XSD (XML schema) that - again in machine-readable form - defines the parameter types used.

Based on those two pieces of information, the WCF client side import can create C# or VB.NET classes that

- mirror the exact service implementation on the service side - same method names, same parameters expected and returned
- create the necessary data classes - again in C# or VB.NET - based off of the XML schema file

So in the end - it's really not magic. It's the beauty of self-describing services and a bit of code generation that reads that metadata and creates client-side proxy classes from that metadata description

If you're interested in more details about metadata, read the [MSDN docs on WCF metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731823.aspx) - quite extensive and in-depth.

Comment: I notice that I can put a lot of compiled service assemblies in the Bin folder, and add quite a lot of svc files exposing the service types contained in those assemblies. Question is, for each of the svc file, it will take a lot of effort to reflect through all the assemblies to locate the corresponding service type. I can think of no other way to do this except reflection. But isn't reflection too much cost?

Comment: @smikipedia: a svc file knows exactly what ServiceHost or ServiceHostFactory it needs; this can be evaluated once by inspecting the assemblies, and then you have that info available. Once the WCF runtime knows which assembly each svc file needs, there's no reflection or other time-consuming evaluation involved anymore... so I guess it might be a bit of a startup cost, but shouldn't be too bad

Comment: Note that IIS has almost nothing to do with this.

Comment: @John Saunders: true - it's really the WCF runtime components that do all the heavy lifting; IIS is only used to instantiate a `ServiceHost` or `ServiceHostFactory` upon the first request coming in

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s stated, the "Add Service Reference" button runs a tool that collects the metadata from the service, and generates client code from it.

I just wanted to add that if you want to view that metadata (WSDL) yourself, you can just add "?wsdl" to your URL:

```
http://localhost/MyService.svc?wsdl
```

One WSDL document will chain to many others, so you would have to make several requests to dig through them all, but it is interesting to see how the data types and contracts are transmitted.

Also, if you want to prevent other people from automatically generating a client to your service, you can disable the WSDL by removing the "mex" (Metadata EXchange) endpoint from your WCF configuration.